# How to modify & extend Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I know that to use Nokogiri, one needs to run:

```
gem install nokogiri
```

and have `require 'nokogiri'` in the ruby file that use nokogiri.
However, I am trying to customize Nokogiri so I need to be able to call the Nokogiri project. What I have done:

1. Download the Nokogiri project from
   https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri
2. Make some changes.

So what I want is to be able to call and run this modified Nokogiri, not the Nokogiri that I install via `gem install Nokogiri`. Does anyone know ?

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, Nokogiri can already parse HTML using Nokogiri::HTML(...)

Comment: OK sure, then you might want to edit your question title.

Comment: sorry for the confusing title

Comment: Why do you want to customize Nokogiri?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're developing your modifications, you probably want the fewest steps between making a code change and seeing the results. In that case you probably want to load the code you're working on directly.

If you're using bundler, you can add:

```
gem 'nokogiri', :path => "/some/path/to/my/copy/of/nokogiri"
```

If you're just coding this bare, you can do:

```
$:.unshift("/some/path/to/my/copy/of/nokogiri/lib")
require 'nokogiri'
```

Once you're happy with your modifications, you might want to create your own gem that includes them. This way, you're not relying on your nokogiri gem code being in a particular location, etc. To do that, you'll need to [create a gemspec](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/04/02/using-gemspecs-as-intended/). Note that you should either change the gem name (difficult) or the version (easy), to differentiate your gem from the existing nokogiri gem you're using.

Then:

```
rake gem
rake install_gem
```

And use the gem as normal in your main project, i.e. `gem 'nokogiri'` or `require 'nokogiri'`.

Comment: Thank you. If I use require 'nokogiri', do I just need to unshift the 'lib' folder only ?

Comment: Yes, the /lib is intentional; when you use bundler it does that part for you, but if you're requiring the gem yourself you need to point the load path to the lib folder, not the top-level folder.

Comment: how do you figure it out ? I didn't see in any documentation?

Comment: Well I've been doing ruby development for about 5 years; I can't remember where I picked this up specifically. It all comes with time :).

Comment: When I uninstall Nokogiri, my script stopped working. It means the script I wrote still used the installed nokogiri, not the customized one.

Comment: Without seeing your code I can't tell what the issue is for sure; but as long as (1) the path to your version of nokogiri is correct, including /lib, (2) you only require nokogiri AFTER you unshift the load path, (3) there is a nokogiri.rb file in /lib/ (there is normally), then it should definitely pull in your version of nokogiri.

Comment: I just write some simple code to test: $:.unshift("/path/to/nokogiri/lib") require 'nokogiri' html = "<html><body></body></html>" p = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

Comment: When I run it gives me error: cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri. That is a line in the file nokogiri.rb: require 'nokogiri/nokogiri'.

Comment: I found why that didn't work. I need to build the project first. Thanks.